# fs.writeFileSync outputs an empty file

Tags: javascript

```
function populateWithKeywordsAndIds(list) {
    var newList = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        //some computation goes in here that i think is not relevant
        newList[x] = y;
    }
    fs.writeFileSync('./firstJSONWritten.js', newList);
    console.log(newList);
    return newList;
}

populateWithKeywordsAndIds(someList);
```

After i run this, firstJSONWritten.js is an empty file.
The call to populateWithKeywordsAndIds(someList) is happening in the body of a .then() method of a promise.

Comment: What are `x` and `y` in your for loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`writeFile`/`writeFileSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefilesync_file_data_options) is not defined to accept a standard array as the data. You can pass it a string, a `Buffer`, or a `Uint8Array`, but not just an array. So it's not surprising you're getting odd results. (It *may* be trying to convert that array into a buffer, but if so, it's undefined behavior, and who knows how it's interpreting the contents...)

---

Side note:

> The call to populateWithKeywordsAndIds(someList) is happening in the body of a .then() method of a promise.

Then there's no reason to use the synchronous version of `writeFile`; you're *already* doing asynchronous handling. Use `writeFile` instead, to avoid unnecessarily tying up the JavaScript thread waiting on I/O.